# Bootstrap jumbotron relative to content

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a singlepage layout using jquery onepage scroll so everything is placed inside  tags. Then inside I have the basic structure of

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-12">
      <div class="jumbotron">

       CONTENT


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The content on the inside isnt being placed in the jumbotron visually, and I have to explicitly move things with absolute bottom positioning. This obviously isnt working well as some content can be longer then others and will expand outside the jumbotron. Any ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Can you post a link to your code? It would be easier to debug with a working example or some CSS. Anyway, here is a possible solution.

Add the row inside the jumbotron. The row element comes with a clearfix already in it's style so that may help to contain the content. If that doesn't help, add the clearfix class to the container element.

```
<div class="container clearfix">
   <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-12">

       CONTENT

         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% on what you're asking but does the following fix your issue?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">

       TOP CONTENT


  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-12">
        REST OF PAGE CONTENT
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Jumbotrons** are really for making header content look bold and stand out.

Comment: I think placing content in the jumbotron is what's screwing with the responsiveness of certain things.